# How to reformat (transform) my json results with javascript?

Tags: json, loops, format, transformation

I have a simple loop that extracts a subset of json objects from a larger dataset.

```
function getData(d) {

    var data = {};

    for (var i=0; i < d.length; i++){
        data[i] = {
            'date'  :   d[i].date,
            'light' :   Math.round(d[i].details.light/60),
            'deep'  :   Math.round(d[i].details.deep/60),
            'awake' :   Math.round(d[i].details.awake/60),
            'duration': Math.round(d[i].details.duration/60),
            'quality':  Math.round(d[i].details.quality*10)
            };
        console.log(data[i]);
    };
    return data;
}

getData(d);
```

It generates json results in the form of,

```
{
   date: 20150809, 
   light: 168, 
   deep: 206, 
   awake: 64, 
   duration: 438,
   quality: 100
}, ...
```

How might I get this into the desired form,

```
   [{
       "key":"light",
       "date":20150809,
       "value":168
    },
    {
       "key":"deep",
       "date": 20150809,
       "value":206
    },
    {
       "key":"awake",
       "date":20150809,
       "value":64
    },
    {
       "key":"duration",
       "date": 20150809,
       "value":438
    }, 
    ...
    {
       "key":"quality",
       "date":20150809,
       "value":6100
    }]
```

My question is, how might I achieve this without iterating over the dataset five times (once for each of the 5 key types)? I assume at least a minimum of one iteration would be required. A `jquery` solution would be acceptable.

I'm seeking one array containing all the json objects as opposed to an associative array of nested objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your data is in a array in this format :

```
var data = [
   {
       date: 20150809,
       light: 168,
       deep: 206,
       awake: 64,
       duration: 438,
       quality: 100
    },
    {
       date: 20153203,
       light: 2,
       deep: 21,
       awake: 21,
       duration: 21,
       quality: 32
    }
    ... 
    ];
```

You can try something like this :

```
var results = [];

data.forEach(function(e) {
  for (var key in e) {
    if (key !== 'date')
      results.push({
        key  : key,
        date : e.date,
        value : e[key]
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought that he didn't want a loop to iterate over the keys when he said "without iterating over the dataset five times (once for each key)"

Comment: I was a too hasty in accepting this as a solution initially (sorry folks). Zainwar's solution makes an array of arrays, each containing 3 objects. Ideally, I'm seeking one array containing all the json objects as opposed to an associative array.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect these comments. Thanks for taking the time to look at this and offer suggestions. It really is appreciated.

Comment: @ColinA.White can you check now? I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Considering the object

```
{
   date: 20150809, 
   light: 168, 
   deep: 206, 
   awake: 64, 
   duration: 438,
   quality: 100
}
```

You want to turn each key into a object without looping through every object. I would to the following:

```
function convertToJson(obj){
   var myJson = {};
   var myKeys = obj.keys(); // return an array with the keys of the object
   myJson.keys = myKeys[1];
   myJson.date = myKeys[0]; // your date
   myJson.value = obj.light;
   ... // do the same with the rest of the elements, if you don't want to loop.

  return JSON.stringfy(myJson);       
}
```

I'm no javascript guru, so I appreciate any feedback.